# Generate fat aar using android studio and gradle to include generated code

Tags: android, aar

Is there a way to build a fat aar that includes all the generated code (for example, dagger and ButterKnife generated files) so the client does not have to compile those and is free of their dependency?

I'm trying to make an already made application "plug and play" in which we provide an `aar` to the client and have to import it. Currently it works but they need to import all our dependencies as well and their version of those dependencies (for example `dagger` might clash with ours. Also they need to build the generated files.

I have looked at the `fat-aar` plugin for gradle but it seems like it is outdated and does not work with recent android studio and gradle versions.